# syntax error :syntax error near unexpected token `

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Now ,i want to do string comparison using ifeq method.

```
ifeq ($$(FILE1_NAME),"$$($$(PKG)_NAME) $$($$(PKG)_VERSION)") \
 patch my file; \
else \
 patch default file ;\
endif
```

while building there are this expansion below.

```
ifeq ("FILE8","FILE1")
```

but its showing

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `"file8_name","file1_name"'.
```

even i tried indentation by removing white space like anything but still shows error.
is there a way to do string comparison other than ifeq ?

Thanks,
ngmns

Comment: How do you know that that is the expansion? What happens if you hard-code it?

Comment: Thanks and it worked for below method.
if test "$$($$(PKG)_FILE)" = "PKG_FILE" \
-o "$$($$(PKG)_NAME2)" = "PKG_NAME2"; then \

Comment: You can take a look at a GNUmake library which provides for string and integer comparison (in make itself): [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt). Notice however that strings in make have no delimiters (e.g. "somestring") and therefor spaces inside strings make it extremely tricky to handle them.